# Synchronous and Asynchronous operation on reading a file using multithreading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have scenario like reading two text files using multithreading in c#.net. How can i implement this scenario synchronously using multithreading.

Comment: Create a method which initiates the two threads but waits for them to finish before returning to the calling scope.

Comment: How do you use multithrreading?

Comment: Look into using the Task Parallel Library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Lock the access to the file so that only one thread can access it.

Or maybe you intent for the results of the read to be processed shyncronouslly just invoke an event on both threads when done and lock on the event.